# PHP Mysql select statement to display that day records ONLY

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing a system that should output the total number of sms sent in a day. It also should separate the delivered ones and the ones that failed.
It should only out put the records for that day only... like only the records for that day. 
My database is smsdb.

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE smsdb (
     id INT(6) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
     sms_text VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
     receiver_number VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     time_sent DATETIME,
     status VARCHAR(20) )";


//I tried to use the command to display todays records but I get all records even for other days.

$sql = ("SELECT DATE(time_sent) AS date, COUNT(*) as total_sent, SUM(status = 'Success') as delivered,SUM(status = 'failed') AS failed FROM smsdb GROUP BY DATE(time_sent) ");
```

I only want total records for this day only.
Kindly, anyone help me

Comment: Your query references a status column that does not exist in the table. Could you please update your question with the correct table definition?

Comment: There is no where condition

Comment: What type of field  time_sent is?

Comment: You need to put where condition on time_sent field for current date

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the question. I purposely removed it for debugging @chocochaos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just filter in the where criteria for the current date:

```
SELECT
    DATE(time_sent) AS date,
    COUNT(*) as total_sent,
    SUM(case when status = 'Success' then 1 else 0 end) as delivered,
    SUM(case when status = 'failed' then 1 else 0 end) AS failed
FROM smsdb
WHERE date(time_sent)=curdate()
GROUP BY DATE(time_sent)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not putting in a date filter. You can either pass it in as a variable, so you can select other days:

```
$sql = ("SELECT DATE(time_sent) AS date, COUNT(*) as total_sent, SUM(status = 'Success') as delivered,SUM(status = 'failed') AS failed FROM smsdb WHERE DATE(time_sent) = '$date_selected'");
```

Note that you really ought to bind parameters for this, but this will give you an idea.

The other option if you always want it to be the current day is use the `CURDATE()` function:

```
$sql = ("SELECT DATE(time_sent) AS date, COUNT(*) as total_sent, SUM(status = 'Success') as delivered,SUM(status = 'failed') AS failed FROM smsdb WHERE DATE(time_sent) = CURDATE()");
```